# How to make one of three inputs type button requierd required

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation, required

My problem is that I have one form with some fields and three inputs type button, they all represents one message. I want to make chooseing one of three messages required. My code is bellow:

```
<input id="poruka1" type="button"  class="hm_datumibtn poruka" name="poruka1" value="Pored mene, sve želje "  >


 <input id="poruka2" type="button"  class="hm_datumibtn poruka" name="poruka2" value="Pored sebe, sve želje " >




<input id="poruka3" type="button"  class="hm_datumibtn poruka" name="poruka3" value="Pored tebe, sve želje "  >
```

Do you have any idea how can I solve this kind of problem?

```
<script>


            function upis(){

                //var datum = $(this).find('.datum').val();
                //var poruka = $(this).find('.poruka').val();
                //var poruka = $(this).attr('value');
                if (poruka_forma.poruka1.value == '' && poruka_forma.poruka2.value == ''&& poruka_forma.poruka3.value == '') {
                    alert('You have to choose message.');
                    return false;
                }
                else {
                    myForm.submit();
                }

                var ime = document.getElementById("ime").value;
                var ime_slavljenik = document.getElementById("ime_slavljenik").value;
                var elementsdate = document.getElementsByClassName("selected_date");
                var datum = elementsdate[0].value;
                var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("selected");
                var poruka = elements[0].value;

                //var poruka = document.getElementById("poruka").value;


                //var datum = document.getElementById("datum").value;
                //var poruka = document.getElementById("poruka").value;
                //var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
                //var dataString = "ime="+encodeURIComponent(ime)+"&ime_slavljenik="+encodeURIComponent(ime_slavljenik);

            $.ajax({

                  type:"post",
                  url: "upis.php",
                  cashe: false,
                  //data: dataString+'&datum='+datum+'&poruka='+poruka,
                  data: {ime:ime,ime_slavljenik:ime_slavljenik,datum:datum, poruka:poruka},
                  success: function(data){
                      //window.alert(data);
                      document.getElementById("placefortableanketa").innerHTML = data;
                  },
                  error: function (req, status, err) {
                console.log('Something went wrong', status, err);
                }
              })
              return false;
        }
        </script>
```

Comment: Use radio button instead of button

Comment: What have you tried? We're not a free code-writing service.

Comment: Here is a script that I use to take values from form, buttons as well. I am trying not to use radio buttons becaues of design that I got, and they are not so goog for styling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you might want to use `<input type="radio" />` instead. Example:

```html
<form>
    <input type="radio" id="radio_btn_1" name="radio_btn" value="choice_1" required="required" checked="checked" /><label for="radio_btn_1">Choice 1</label><br />
    <input type="radio" id="radio_btn_2"  name="radio_btn" value="choice_2" required="required" /><label for="radio_btn_2">Choice 2</label><br />
    <input type="radio" id="radio_btn_3"  name="radio_btn" value="choice_3" required="required" /><label for="radio_btn_3">Choice 3</label><br />
</form>
```

You can add `required` attributes to make them *required*. Also, adding `checked` attributes will make a radio button selected by *default*.

You can also use `<label>` with `for` attribute. When that `label` is clicked, it selects a radio button that it refers to by `id` in its `for` attribute.

**Edit**: I saw your comment that you don't want to use radio buttons because of the design. You can actually hide the radio buttons, and just use `<label>` with `for` attributes. Example:

```html
<style>
    #radio_btn_1:checked + label{background-color:red;}
    #radio_btn_2:checked + label{background-color:red;}
    #radio_btn_3:checked + label{background-color:red;}
</style>
<form>
    <input style="display:none;" type="radio" id="radio_btn_1" name="radio_btn" value="choice_1" required="required" checked="checked" /><label for="radio_btn_1">Choice 1</label><br />
    <input style="display:none;" type="radio" id="radio_btn_2"  name="radio_btn" value="choice_2" required="required" /><label for="radio_btn_2">Choice 2</label><br />
    <input style="display:none;" type="radio" id="radio_btn_3"  name="radio_btn" value="choice_3" required="required" /><label for="radio_btn_3">Choice 3</label><br />
</form>
```